# App Crashes on Storing the Bitmap on Android 10 even if Target Sdk is set to 28?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mediastore

I am attaching the Bitmap to the Imageview by storing in the MediaStore. It works fine in all the device below android 10, but when crash occured in pixel. My android id targeted to sdk 28

```
try {
                Bitmap thePic = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, croppedPicUri);
                if(thePic != null){
                    imgProfileIcon.SetImageBitmap(thePic);

                //mediaStorageDir = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDcim);
                mediaStorageDir = GetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
                if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
                {
                    mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs();
                }


                // Create a media file name
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").Format(new Java.Util.Date());
                sendFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.Path + File.Separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png");

                String path_ = MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(this.ContentResolver, thePic, "Title", null);
                if (path_ != null){
                    Uri tempUri = Uri.Parse(path_);
                    path = GetPathToImage(tempUri);
                }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Bundle extras : " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
```

{Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Title image/jpeg
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <205bc242eb64455b94479843fca3eeb7>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00018] in <205bc242eb64455b94479843fca3eeb7>:0 
  at Android.Provider.MediaStore+Images+Media.InsertImage (Android.Content.ContentResolver cr, Android.Graphics.Bitmap source, System.String title, System.String description) [0x0008d] in <072ebd6d3ae947ac8b3980f8fd1aeee1>:0 
  at EventApp.ProfileListActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00200] in D:\EventApp\EventApp\Activity\ProfileListActivity.cs:1310 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Title image/jpeg
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2079)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1828)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.createPending(MediaStore.java:616)
    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:1771)

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Title image/jpeg` there's your error

Comment: yes this is an exception occured

Comment: Maybe a file with that filename already exists?

Comment: You are not using `sendFile`  (and timestamp) and insert every bitmap in the mediastore under the name "Title".

Comment: @DennisSchroer No the file name is unique everytime since the timestamp changes in every second

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, the pixel is android 8.1. And I have tested the code with Google Pixel, and it works well.

Comment: No pixel should be on Andorid 10. Inspite of that in all the versions it works fine

Comment: Then what does this meaning of this words :`when crash occured in pixe`  ? I am confused with this.

Comment: After cropping done when the image is attached to imageview MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage this line of code crashes the app

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Scoped Storage Access is an abort of idea and implementation. 1 day to save a file. security exceptions and intents that you can't fire if you are on a service. Insane.

Answer (score 8):

Let's consider:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description)
```

Let's apply it to a real example:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), imageToSave, "ThisIsImageTitleString", null);
```

You will notice that this safely saves any type of bitmap in memory.
But how is the output bitmap name?

First time:

> ThisIsImageTitleString

Second time:

> ThisIsImageTitleString(2)

...

32th time:

> ThisIsImageTitleString(32)

33th time:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures ThisIsImageTitleString image/jpeg

Simple solution: add a **timestamp**.

Declare this as constant ( static or non static according to what you need )

```
static Date currentTime;
```

and then change MediaStore way to save bitmaps to:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), imageToSave, "ThisIsImageTitleString" + " - " + (currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()), null);
```

**Please note:** `(currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime())`

Comment: For timestamp, `System.currentTimeMillis()` can also be used.

Comment: here time stamp is mendatory for

Answer (score 3):

Change/Create file with the use of math's random function rather then time stamp and make sure it FileOutputStream object is going to flush.
for the reference,

```
 private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
         if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                    }
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ())
          file.delete (); 
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Could you further explain why one would use a random number instead of a timestamp, which is more unique?

Comment: It doesn´t solve the problem! , besides the use of Environment class is deprecated for android 10!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that while saving image via `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description)` method, `title` param must be specified explicitly on Android 10. In other way file name will look like this: `Image`. Every next image will be saved as `Image (n)`. App throws an error after `n` reaches value of 32.

Answer (score 1):

replace "Title" to File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png

eg.`String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage,   File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png", null);`

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, this method is deprecated in API 29.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media

```
insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, String name, String description)

This method was deprecated in API level 29. inserting of images should be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer control over lifecycle.
```

You should use MediaColumns#IS_PENDING for the devices using API 29+.

More info:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/media#pending-media-files

Comment: But My Target Api is 28 not 29

Comment: Can you please add a timestamp to your "Title" + System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: yaa i tried that yesterday. This fixed the issue but dont know why